# Matrix in SO(d) be expressed as a continuous operator.

Tags: matrices

$SO(d)$ is the d square rotation matrix group. I am wondering if we can express all rotation on sphere $S^{d-1}$ as a continuous function operator $f(t)$, i.e. for any $Q\in SO(d)$, there exists a $t\in R$, $Q=f(t)$. Here $f$ is a continuous function with respect to $t$.

Intuitively, I want to try $f(t)=e^{tA}$ with $A$ a fixed matrix.

Also, do you have any reference about this part? I need some refered material to go deep in this area.

Thanks very much.

Comment: A useful point of view is to take SO(d) as a matrix lie group, and then any such A can be viewed as a linear combination of generators, living in so(d).  Brian C Hall has a very accessible introduction to matrix lie groups which explains all this and more very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

What is the case is that if $A$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, then $\exp(A)$ 
(as defined by the exponential power series) is an element of $\text{SO}(n)$
and that all elements of $\text{SO}(n)$ can be obtained this way.

So, given $Q\in\text{SO}(n)$ there is a function of the form $f(t)=\exp(tA)$
with $f(0)=I$ and $f(1)=Q$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I want this function $f$ is a mapping from a continuous sub interval of $R$, and mapping onto $SO(d)$. Or from a continuous area of $R^{m}$ onto $SO(d)$ with some integer $m$.

Comment: I think it's important to note that this decomposition is not unique.  Even picking out the "minimum" A may change discontinuously when changing the final rotation Q, or fail to converge.   Nor is computing such an A always easy; you can try computing a matrix logarithm by e.g. power series, but the standard ways only really work near the origin.